# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'applyFilterAsync'

Tags: javascript, api, tableau-api

I am trying to show a Dashboard in my webpage via Tableau JavaScript api. My dashboard does gets initialized but when I try to filter, it gives me an error as

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'applyFilterAsync'
```

Here's my code where it gives error

```
activeSheet.applyFilterAsync('Region', 'Asia', tableauSoftware.FilterUpdateType.ADD);
```

Any idea why this error?

**UPDATE:**
I was however able to use the applyFilterAsync function with the published sheet. Is this function not available for dashboards?

Answer (score 1):

**sheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().getWorksheets()[N];** /* with dashboard it is needed to specify the worksheet number.

**sheet.applyFilterAsync(filtername, value, 'REPLACE');**